# Preview Unsaved Page Changes in OctoberCMS on Font End

Tags: octobercms

Is there a way to preview a page change without saving it first?

The page preview button simply displays the page on the front end, but a save is required to see changes.

I am looking for a draft type option, or the preview button to actually preview the unsaved changes within the full layout and true template context, aka "front end", not just a WYSIWYG.

Currently I have to create a hidden sandbox page, copy the content from the live page to the sandbox page, make changes and review them in the front end, then copy all new sandbox changes back to the live page.

Is there not a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a preview without saving the page. But, you can add the `hidden` checkbox to be only accesible by logged-in admin. See here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umjI8.png]

You now have a private sandbox!

Hope it's help.